# rewriting python program in cpp, how to fill in the header field in msg

Tags: ros, python, c++, header, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am reading the [pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving the arm through a Cartesian pose trajectory](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20through%20a%20Cartesian%20pose%20trajectory).

At the end of this tutorial, there is a test client program written in python, which send Cartesian trajectories to the service. I got a problem when I was trying to rewrite it in c++.

```
  13 #execute a Cartesian trajpr2_controllersTutorialsMoving the arm through a Cartesian pose trajectoryectory defined by a root frame, a list of 
  14 #positions (x,y,z), and a list of orientations (quaternions: x,y,z,w)
  15 def call_execute_cartesian_ik_trajectory(frame, positions, orientations):
  16     rospy.wait_for_service("execute_cartesian_ik_trajectory")
  17 
  18     #fill in the header (don't need seq)
  19     header = roslib.msg.Header()
  20     header.frame_id = frame
  21     header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
```

Here the header was filled, I am not sure if I need to do the same thing in c++ and if so, what's the corresponding code that I should be using?

Maybe a very basic question, but I just couldn't find the answer and very confused.
Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10840/rewriting-python-program-in-cpp,-how-to-fill-in-the-header-field-in-msg/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The corresponding code for filling a header would be:

```
srv.header.frame_id = frame;
srv.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bigbellmercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40244/bigbellmercy/) on 2020-05-10**:
In the above, instead of 'frame' you can fill a string constant as like below:

```
srv.header.frame_id = "your_frame";
```